# Why do my admin drop down menu doesn't show up when i try to create my own settings for a css customizable moodle theme?

Tags: php, css, admin, moodle

I am creating a new moodle theme which the css needs to be customizable. By "customizable", i mean that from the admin page you can edit for exemple, the color of your background.

I followed the tutorial from https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes, which is great but should be, from my opinion, about the same parent theme for each parts of it.

My page is displaying well at the exception of my admin drop down menu (so i can't see my theme editing page). Everything was fine before i tried to setup my own settings just as the tutorial.

I assume that i probably made a mistake by adaptating my theme from the tutorial but i'm completly lost right now.

We are here in the 'theme/mytheme' directory.

File 'settings.php' :

```php
<?php

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$name = 'theme_mytheme/backcolor';
$title = get_string('backcolor', 'theme_mytheme');
$desc = get_string('backcolor_desc', 'theme_mytheme');
$setting = new admin_setting_configcolourpicker($name, $title, $desc, '#ffffff');
$setting->set_updatedcallback('theme_reset_all_caches');
$page->add($setting);

?>
```

File 'lib.php':

```php
<?php

 defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die;

 function theme_mytheme_process_css($css, $theme) {

    // Set custom CSS.
    if (!empty($theme->settings->customcss)) {
        $customcss = $theme->settings->customcss;
    } else {
        $customcss = null;
    }
    $css = theme_mytheme_set_customcss($css, $customcss);
    $defaults = array(
        '[[setting:backcolor]]' => '#FFFFFF',
    );

    foreach ($theme->settings as $key => $val) {
        if (array_key_exists('[[setting:'.$key.']]', $defaults) && !empty($val)) {
            $defaults['[[setting:'.$key.']]'] = $val;
        }
    }

    $homebkg = '';
    if (!empty($theme->settings->homebk)) {
        $homebkg = $theme->setting_file_url('homebk', 'homebk');
        $homebkg = 'background-image: url("' . $homebkg . '");';
    }
    $defaults['[[setting:homebkg]]'] = $homebkg;

    // Replace the CSS with values from the $defaults array.
    $css = strtr($css, $defaults);
    if (empty($theme->settings->tilesshowallcontacts) || $theme->settings->tilesshowallcontacts == false) {
        $css = theme_mytheme_set_tilesshowallcontacts($css, false);
    } else {
        $css = theme_mytheme_set_tilesshowallcontacts($css, true);
    }
    return $css;
}


function theme_mytheme_set_customcss($css, $customcss) {
    $tag = '[[setting:customcss]]';
    $replacement = $customcss;
    if (is_null($replacement)) {
        $replacement = '';
    }

    $css = str_replace($tag, $replacement, $css);

    return $css;
}

function theme_mytheme_set_tilesshowallcontacts($css, $display) {
    $tag = '[[setting:tilesshowallcontacts]]';
    if ($display) {
        $replacement = 'block';
    } else {
        $replacement = 'none';
    }
    $css = str_replace($tag, $replacement, $css);
    return $css;
}

function theme_mytheme_pluginfile($course, $cm, $context, $filearea, $args, $forcedownload, array $options = array()) {
    if ($context->contextlevel == CONTEXT_SYSTEM &&
    ($filearea === 'logo' || $filearea === 'smalllogo' || $filearea === 'backgroundimage')) {
        $theme = theme_config::load('mytheme');
        // By default, theme files must be cache-able by both browsers and proxies.
        if (!array_key_exists('cacheability', $options)) {
            $options['cacheability'] = 'public';
        }
        return $theme->setting_file_serve($filearea, $args, $forcedownload, $options);
    } else {
        send_file_not_found();
    }
}
?>
```

File 'config.php' :

```php
<?php

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$THEME->name = 'mytheme';
$THEME->sheets = array('styles');
$THEME->editor_sheets = array();
$THEME->parents = array('base');
$THEME->yuicssmodules = array();

$THEME->scss = function($theme) {
    return theme_mytheme_get_pre_scss($theme);
};

$THEME->layouts = array(
    // Most backwards compatible layout without the blocks - this is the layout used by default
    'base' => array(
        'theme' => 'mytheme',
        'file' => 'standard.php',
        'regions' => array(),
    ),
    'standard' => array(
        'theme' => 'mytheme',
        'file' => 'standard.php',
        'regions' => array('side-pre', 'side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-pre',
    ),
    'frontpage' => array(
        'theme' => 'mytheme',
        'file' => 'standard.php',
        'regions' => array('side-pre', 'side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-post'
    )
);

$THEME->csspostprocess = 'theme_mytheme_process_css';

?>
```

I feel sorry for passing my complete files but it can't be pertinent if i don't...